# How can I manage shared views?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, view, module

I have a custom controller class that is extended by controllers in two different modules. They will share some views.

Two questions:

1. Where should I place these shared views?
2. Do I have to call `$this->render('view');` at the end of every action or is there something I can do to avoid that?

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate what you mean? It's not 100% clear at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the controllers are in the same module, you could create a dedicated directory for the shared view scripts, for instance a directory in `views` called `shared`.

In the controller actions that will use the shared views, you can tell the view renderer to use them by adding this in your controller action:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('shared/theView', null, true);
// causes views/shared/the-view.phtml to be used instead of views/controller/action.phtml
```

This way you don't have to manually call render and then terminate processing.